# MySQL backup process slowing down inserts and updates

Tags: sql, database, backup, mysql

Currently i am using the mysqldump program to create backups, below is an example of how i run it.

```
mysqldump --opt --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --add-drop-database 
--no-autocommit -u user -ppassword  --databases db > dbbackup.sql
```

I perform alot of inserts and updates on my database through out the day, but when this process starts it can really slow  the inserts and updates down, does anyone see any flaw in the way i am backing it up ? (e.g. tables being locked), or is there a way i can improve the backup process so it doesn't effect my inserts and updates as much?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The absolutely best way of doing this without disturbing the production database is to have a master/slave replication set up, you then do the dump from the slave database.

More on MySQL replication here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html

Comment: Couple of queries: does replication happens in idle or real time? If it's during idle time then sync is not guaranteed. Or if it's during real time then it's a network overhead(unless dedicated N/W link) too.

Comment: The slave would have to be locked anyways during the dump, so delays as small as the network overhead won't matter much. It's just a matter of not having the production database getting slow during the backup. But you can set up a slave to either replicate in real time or with a delay, if this was your question?

Answer (score 0):

Even with --skip-lock-tables, mysqldump will issue a READ lock on every table to keep consistency. 
Using mysqldump will always lock your database. To perform hot mysql backups, you will need to either set up a slave (that implies some costs) or using some dedicated tools like Percona Xtrabackup (http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup), and that is **if your database is innoDB** (we use xtrabackup for terabytes of data without an issue, on slaves. If your database is not as big, having a slave and locking it to perform the backup shouldn't be that big of a deal :) )